# Youtube preg_match for endscreen

Tags: php

I’ve been trying to get PHP `preg_match` to work with `feature=endscreen` youtube URL's with no luck. Any suggestions.

```
(preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match))
```

example input = http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=uOHvZjiDANg
required output = uOHvZjiDANg

Comment: Can you include a sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

this is my tested code try it

```
<?php

function parse_yturl($url) 
{
    $pattern = '#^(?:https?://)?';    # Optional URL scheme. Either http or https.
    $pattern .= '(?:www\.)?';         #  Optional www subdomain.
    $pattern .= '(?:';                #  Group host alternatives:
    $pattern .=   'youtu\.be/';       #    Either youtu.be,
    $pattern .=   '|youtube\.com';    #    or youtube.com
    $pattern .=   '(?:';              #    Group path alternatives:
    $pattern .=     '/embed/';        #      Either /embed/,
    $pattern .=     '|/v/';           #      or /v/,
    $pattern .=     '|/watch\?v=';    #      or /watch?v=,    
    $pattern .=     '|/watch\?.+&v='; #      or /watch?other_param&v=
    $pattern .=   ')';                #    End path alternatives.
    $pattern .= ')';                  #  End host alternatives.
    $pattern .= '([\w-]{11})';        # 11 characters (Length of Youtube video ids).
    $pattern .= '(?:.+)?$#x';         # Optional other ending URL parameters.
    preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    return (isset($matches[1])) ? $matches[1] : false;
}


echo parse_yturl('http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=uOHvZjiDANg');

?>
```

output = uOHvZjiDANg

Source: https://github.com/eyecatchup/php-yt_downloader/blob/master/youtube-dl.class.php#L406

Comment: this is the exact one I’m using but the only problem is it's not working for feature=endscreen YouTube URL's. All the rest seem to be working correctly.

Comment: I have modify my answer please take a look. i am sure it is very help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(preg_match('/youtube\.com\/(v\/|watch\?v=)([\w\-]+)/', $url, $match)){; $vid=$match[2]; 
}
print "$vid";
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying a complex regex I would suggest this:

1. Parse the URL using [parse_url function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and extract querystring.
2. Take query string from above step and call [parse_str function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get separate query parameters into variables.